# Accessing .xml file from MainActivity class

Tags: android, listview

We have **MainActivity.class** , **activity_main.xml** and **firstlayout.xml.**

In **firstlayout.xml** there is a `listview`. I am in **MainActivity.class** and I want to access my `listview.` How can I do that when my `listview` is in another **.xml** file.

Something like

> ListView lstview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstview)

does not work, because I get a

> null reference error

because my listview is not in mainactivity.xml. I also tried

> setcontentView(R.layout.firstlayout)

but it didn't work either.

```
How can I access a xml file which is NOT in main_activity.xml ?
```

Comment: you can do this by including the firstlayout .xml in mainactivity.xml and also by using LayoutInflater to inflate the Listview but not directly

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539723/how-to-inflate-a-listview-to-a-view already answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inflate a ListView to a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539723/how-to-inflate-a-listview-to-a-view)

Comment: Please post your xml files and MainActivity code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible way for useing  ListView in your mainActivity.

1) You can simply include that layout (**firstlayout.xml**) into you **activity_main.xml**  file.

example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/firstlayout"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />
```

2) The second option is Layout Inflater.You can simply add other layout file directly into your java file.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstlayout, this);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question: Shouldn't it be 
$$ inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstlayout, null); $$  ?

Comment: inflater.inflate(int resource,ViewGroup root); is the format of inflater method.
use can understand the concept of inflater, with help of this tutorial:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxVeFwtIpVc .

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate the view with the layout inflater:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.firstlayout,
                           parentView, //the view that logically contains the list view, or just the base view in the main layout
                           false // false if you want to attach the list view to the parent, true otherwise
                           );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate your own:

```
View firstLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.firstlayout, null, false);
ListView listView = (ListView) firstLayout.findViewById(R.id.lstView);
```

Just ensure that `firstlayout` has a `ListView` with id `lstview`.